# 2008 hhr LT 2.4 turn on air conditioner or heater on recirculating air and it bogs down almost dieing

Tags: chevrolet, hhr

We had the car in for service and when we got it back the air conditioning stop working and would bog down engine. So now its getting colder and noticed my heat is not hot anymore and if i have it on outside air its fine but i switch it ro recirculating air it bogs it down as well. Am usually pretty good with cars but not able to figure this out and no check engine light or anything and when i turn them off it goes back to normal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!